# Producer–Consumer & Condition Variables program gets stuck in a infinite loop

Tags: c, concurrency, infinite-loop

When I run my program( running in C ) with usleep it gets stuck in an infinite loop. Without usleep the program doesnt run concurrently though. Any help will be much appreciated. 
The program is supposed to allow producers make food while consumers take the food at the same time. My program gets stuck after adding about 5 items and stops. I think it could be a thread not being unlocked but I cant figure it out.

```
#include <pthread.h> 
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <stdlib.h> 
#include <unistd.h>
#include <time.h>
              // rc stands for return code
#define NUM_THREADS 4 // declare consumers
#define NUM_PRODUCERS 2 // declare producers
#define MAX_BUFFER 10 // declare max buffer
pthread_mutex_t bufferBox; // delcare buffer

struct foodItem{           // structure for food
   int serialCode;
   int producer;
   struct foodItem * next;  

};
struct buffer{            // Structure for buffer
  int size;
  struct foodItem * head;
};
struct buffer * myBuffer; 
void addFood(int producer, struct buffer * buffer);
void removeItem(struct buffer * buffer);

int serial;

void addFood(int producer, struct  buffer * buffer){       // ADD TO BUFFER FUNCTION

    struct foodItem * newItem = malloc(sizeof(struct foodItem));
        newItem -> producer = producer;
    newItem -> serialCode = serial;

    if(buffer->size==0){
    buffer-> head = newItem;
        buffer->size++;
    printf("item added serial%d\n",serial);
    serial++;
    }
    else{

    struct foodItem * item = buffer ->head;
    while(item->next != NULL ){
        item = item-> next;
        }
        item ->next =newItem;
            buffer->size++;
        printf("item added serial%d\n",serial);
        serial++;   
    }

}
void removeItem(struct buffer * buffer){            //REMOVE FROM BUFFER FUNCTION
    if(buffer->size ==1){
       free(buffer->head);

    }
    else{
             struct foodItem * temp = buffer -> head;
         buffer -> head = buffer ->head->next;
         free(temp);    
    }
    buffer->size--;
    printf("item removed\n");
}
void *Producers(void *threadid){
    int i =11;
       while(i>0){
         if(myBuffer->size < MAX_BUFFER){ 
           pthread_mutex_lock(&bufferBox);
       addFood((int)threadid,  myBuffer);
       addFood((int)threadid,  myBuffer);
       pthread_mutex_unlock(&bufferBox);
      usleep(20000);    
         }   
    else{
    printf("OverFlow\n");
    } 
      i--;
   }
   pthread_exit(NULL); 
}

void *Consumers(void *threadid) {
        usleep(20000);
    int i =6;
    while( i >0){

        if(myBuffer->size > 0){ 
           pthread_mutex_lock(&bufferBox);
       removeItem(myBuffer);

       pthread_mutex_unlock(&bufferBox);
      usleep(15000);
         }   
    else{
    printf("UnderFlow\n");
    }
     i--;
}
    pthread_exit(NULL);


} 




int main (int argc, const char * argv[]) { 
    pthread_t consumers[NUM_THREADS]; 
        pthread_t producers[NUM_PRODUCERS];
    long rc,t,i;    
    int size =0;
        myBuffer = malloc(sizeof(struct buffer));

        for (t=0;t<NUM_PRODUCERS;t++) { 

        printf("Creating Producers %ld\n",t); 
    rc = pthread_create(&producers[t],NULL,Producers,(void *)t); // initial producer
        if (rc) { 
            printf("ERROR return code from pthread_create(): %ld\n",rc); 
            exit(-1); 
        } 
    } 

    //usleep(10000);
    for (t=0;t<NUM_THREADS;t++) { 

        printf("Creating Consumers %ld\n",t); 
    rc = pthread_create(&consumers[t],NULL,Consumers,(void *)t); // initial consumers
        if (rc) { 
            printf("ERROR return code from pthread_create(): %ld\n",rc); 
            exit(-1); 
        } 
    } 
    // wait for threads to exit 
    for(t=0;t<NUM_THREADS;t++) { 
        pthread_join(producers[t], NULL); 
    }

    // wait for threads to exit 
    for(t=0;t<NUM_THREADS;t++) { 
        pthread_join(consumers[t], NULL); 
    } 
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Looks like you forgot to call pthread_mutex_init() for your bufferBox mutex.

Comment: Unsynchronized, non-readonly, non-atomic access to `buffer->size` in multiple threads -> undefined behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to be careful to initialize any data before using it, for example your addFood(...) routine at the top add a line like this

```
newItem -> next = NULL;
```

Similarly in your removeItem(...) function;

```
if(buffer->size ==1){
    free(buffer->head);
    buffer->head = NULL;
}
```

Also as @EOF says in his comment above use the mutex to protect access to buffer->size in your Producers(...) and Consumers(...) routines.  For example;

```
pthread_mutex_lock(&bufferBox);
if(myBuffer->size < MAX_BUFFER) { 
....
pthread_mutex_unlock(&bufferBox);
```

After fixing all of these problems your producers seem to exit last leaving the queue completely full.  Not sure what behavior you expect.